# For the Ant gurus: how do I copy and concat at the same time or in the same manner?

Tags: ant

During my build process I copy files from one directory to another, filtering out some unnecessary text like so:

```
<target name="init-files">
  <copy todir="${resources}/clean" overwrite="true">
    <fileset dir = "${resources}/dirty" />
    <filterchain>
      <tokenfilter>
        <replacestring from="text_to_remove" to="" />
      </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain>
  </copy>
</target>
```

I would like to insert a line of text at the beginning and end of each file being copied.  I cannot use `replacestring` as I can't insert a token - the source text files are generated externally.

`concat` looked like the answer but while I've found how to concatenate a collection of files into a single file (many sources with single destination) I don't see how to add text to each file in a collection (fixed text source with many destination).

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to accomplish this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [`replaceregex` string filter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex) that can be chained with the `replacestring` filter you already have in the tokenfilter:

```
<tokenfilter>
    <replacestring from="text_to_remove" to="" />
    <filetokenizer/>
    <replaceregex pattern="^" replace="PREFIX TEXT${line.separator}" />
    <replaceregex pattern="$" replace="${line.separator}SUFFIX TEXT" />
</tokenfilter>
```

The first one matches the start of each of the files, the second the end.